# How to align text in columns (centered) without removing delimiter?

Tags: bash, shell

I would like to adjust my source centered in columns...

Source:

```
IP | ASN | Prefix        | AS Name           | CN | Domain    | ISP
109.228.12.96 | 8560 | 109.228.0.0/18 | ONEANDONE | DE | fasthosts.com | Fast Hosts LTD
```

Goal:

```
IP            | ASN  | Prefix         | AS Name   | CN | Domain        | ISP
109.228.12.96 | 8560 | 109.228.0.0/18 | ONEANDONE | DE | fasthosts.com | Fast Hosts LTD
```

I tried different things with the command column...but I have double spaces inside:

```
cat Source.txt | sed 's/ *| */@| /g' | column -s '@' -t

IP             | ASN   | Prefix          | AS Name    | CN  | Domain         | ISP
109.228.12.96  | 8560  | 109.228.0.0/18  | ONEANDONE  | DE  | fasthosts.com  | Fast Hosts LTD
```

Is there a way to use column without removing the delimiter...or another solution?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: There is no need for `sed` in your last example: `column -s '|' -o '|' -t  filename` will work.

Comment: I'm using Mac:

    column: illegal option -- o
    usage: column [-tx] [-c columns] [-s sep] [file ...]

Comment: Bummer: `-o, --output-separator separators` are you on a darn Mac? Gotcha...

Comment: How many lines are there in your data files? The issue is finding the longest field in each column. If there are only 2, then you can play with `head` and `tail` to process the 2nd row first and find the max for each field, then you can set a `printf` statement with field widths specified to output your data.

Comment: Here in this case I have only one ip address, but I would like to use this feature also for bulk whois...hundreds of IP addresses.

Comment: I think this is just how BSD `column` works: it puts two spaces at the end of each column. So you could remove one of the spaces by running the output through `sed` again. Or you could write your own `column` utility, but that might be more work than its worth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also do everything in awk. Save the program to **pr.awk** and run

`awk -f pr.awk input.dat`

```
BEGIN {
    FS = "|"

    ARGV[2] = "pass=2"  # a trick to read file two times
    ARGV[3] = ARGV[1]
    ARGC=4
    pass = 1
}

function trim(s) {
    sub(/^[[:space:]]+/, "", s) # remove leading
    sub(/[[:space:]]+$/, "", s) # and trailing whitespaces
    return s
}

pass == 1 {
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
       field = trim($i)
       len   = length(field)
       w[i] = len>w[i] ? len : w[i] # find the maximum width
    }
}

pass == 2 {
    line = ""
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
       field = trim($i)
       s   = i==NF ? field : sprintf("%-" w[i] "s", field)
       sep = i==1  ? ""    : " | "
       line = line sep s
    }
    print line
}
```

Answer (score 1):

column has input sepatator -s and also output seperator -o 
so call is like

cat file | column -t -s '|' -o '|'